# I am trying to write a lotto program

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple fake lotto program (just to have fun with along with my friends and also to give me more practice at programming)

I keep getting the error `SyntaxError: invalid token with an arrow pointing at the number 2 in 02`.

I only have 2 lines at the moment as I like to check my work fairly often as I am writing by using "print" statements to show the progress at random area's. this is all I have so far:

```
#numbers for fake lotto
lotto = (02 03 16 48 56 01 28 33 55 56 10 16 38 43 63 23 49 57 64 67 16 30)

print(lotto)
```

Comment: You should follow a tutorial on Python which should teach you things like [lists](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Lists), which it looks like you wanted. Currently, your code is invalid because items can't be separated by spaces.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never start a number with 0. Many languages will interpret that number as base-8, which is almost definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes should be corrected in your code

- A list requires `,` to separate elements
- Numbers starting with 0 are not considered as base 10 number, as you expect. Number starting with zero indicate hexadecimal number with `0x` prefix. For example, `3` is represented with `0x3` and `15` is represented with `0xF` with hexadecimal notation. Computational representation is different from string representation: you can print `3` with a `0` prefix, with `'{0:02d}'.format(3)`

You should try

```
lotto=(2,3,16,48,56,1,28,33,55,56,10,16,38,43,63,23,49,57,64,67,16,30)
print(lotto)
```

Comment: ok, I have this so far. lotto=('2,3,16,48,56,01,28,33,55,56,10,16,38,43,63,23,49,57,6‌​4,67,16,30') print(lotto) then I put lottoList = lotto.split() .. now I am trying to figure a way to use mode to cycle through the list to come up with how often each number appears. My actual list of numbers in the lotto variable is 600 elements long.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to write a program that will figure out how many times EACH of the 600 elements will appear in my random() list. I put the ' at each end of the list to make it a string rather then having it in int form. but I would like to print out a list of each of the 600 elements followed by the = and how many times it appears.

Comment: I was trying to write a for loop with an if statment and a for loop inside it but could not figure it out as I am still an extreme beginner.

Comment: @MichaelHoward Why do you have quotes inside the list?

Comment: to make certain it was treated as a str rather than a bunch of integers